# Xcode iOS external display mirroring

Tags: ios, xcode, video, mirroring, hdmi

Im working at a local newspaper and I have built a simple video uploading app that we are going to use inside our organization to make it easier to upload videos to our servers.

My issues is that when I'm going to demonstrate it for +100 people i would like to use a projector using a hdmi adapter. So i bought the adapter for my iPhone and it works great if it wasn't for one thing. When i edit the clip before uploading it (the simple editing tool that is a part of the AVfoundation) it dosnt mirror the editing tools to the hdmi screen. The projector just shows the video in fullscreen. So i can't demonstrate the buttons and tools for editing. Everything else works perfectly to mirror by default. Is there some way to force it to truly mirror it instead? Has tried reading Apples official iOS database about it but only found info about when it comes to video playback.

The code for the camera and the editing:

```
// Hides the controls for moving & scaling pictures, or for
// trimming movies. To instead show the controls, use YES.
cameraUI.allowsEditing = YES;
cameraUI.cameraFlashMode = UIImagePickerControllerCameraFlashModeAuto;
cameraUI.videoQuality = UIImagePickerControllerQualityTypeHigh;
cameraUI.delegate = delegate;



    // Show camera view controller.
[controller presentViewController:cameraUI animated:NO completion:nil ];
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way to go is by using the apple tv, and also the recommended one
http://www.apple.com/airplay/

Comment: So it will be a true mirroring in that case if i use a Apple TV instead? It will show the controls of the editor on the Apple TVs hdmi output?

Comment: the apple tv does not use a hdmi, check the link

Comment: No but will the final display show the editing controls inside the app for the viewers?
My worry is that it will only show the fullscreen video on the apple tv as well.